# Reliability of std::hardware_destructive_interference_size

Tags: c++, concurrency, c++17

C++17 introduced constants, which seem to be useful for cache aware programming:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/hardware_destructive_interference_size

```
inline constexpr std::size_t hardware_destructive_interference_size,
inline constexpr std::size_t hardware_constructive_interference_size
```

Though I'm wondered how reliable they could be?
Is it guaranteed that later there will be no new CPU models with the other cache line sizes within the same CPU architecture?

I.e. for x64 cache line size is `64 bytes`. But could it become e.g. `128 bytes` for some future x64 compatible CPU models?
The code, which is compiled for `64 byte` cache line size will eventually become misbehaving.

That cache line size change of course will not break the logic of the code (if that's probably not a heartbleed-like algorithm).
But that could still cause some side effects. E.g. false-sharing protection will stop working.

The reliance on such constants might give feeling like:

> My code is guaranteed by the standard to run correctly platform-independent.

Which actually might be not the right feeling sometimes. Due to hardware changes after the code is compiled.

Or... are there probably any fixed standard cache line sizes per CPU architectures or something like that?

Comment: *My code is guaranteed by the standard to run correctly platform-independent.* This is true.  What is not true is taking a binary from X and trying to run it on Y.  You need to compie the code on Y to get a Y compatible binary.

Comment: Do `not` use `code tags` for things `that` are `not` code.

Comment: These are set by the compiler's design which targets the actual architectures. Examining the source code for these (as you appear to have done) should tell you what that compiler is assuming but you will need to check against the actual CPUI/cache/ram for any specific design to determine the degree it's valid.

Comment: @NathanOliver, This is probably true. But with the limitations. Today we can run  code, which was built 20 years ago. And it's just working because it's still 100% compatible with modern CPU's. The reliance on cache line size give the hidden incompatibility. I.e. code _seems to be compatible_ , but it _is not 100% compatible_.

Comment: These values are just granularity assumed by compiler. Actual cache line size is a runtime property.

Comment: Except that it *is* 100% compatible. "compatible" doesn't mean "optimal".

Comment: Though those constants are designed to write more "optimal" code...

Comment: @AlexanderStepaniuk *'because it's still 100% compatible with modern CPU's'* – hm, maybe we need to consider it the other way round: CPU's are backwards compatible to old code?

Comment: I could imagine that future compilers for x64 might provide command line flags to adjust actual cache line sizes...

Answer (score 0):

... a bit hand-wavy, but too long for a comment:

> Though I'm wondered how reliable they could be?

You only quoted the declarations. For their definition the standard just specifies: `/*implementation-defined*/`. The standard merely guarantees you that a conforming implementation has to provide a definition.

> Is it guaranteed that later there will be no new CPU models with the other cache line sizes within the same CPU architecture?

As far as I understand, that is the whole point of having those constants in the standard. If you compile your code for a different architecture the values will be "automagically" the correct ones. No need for using magic numbers anymore. It is no longer up to you to take care of the architecture you are targeting with respect to cache access, but now it is up to library implementers.

PS: Portable does not mean "compile once, run everywhere", but rather "write once, compile everywhere"